# Javascript Math.round() for two percentages results to a number greater than 100%

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I'm working on a function that gets the length of two arrays, adds them together and get the percentage of each array of the total
Like this

```
var arrLength1 = arr1.length;
var arrLength2 = arr2.length;

var totalLength = arrLength1 + arrLength2;

var arrPercent1 = (arrLength1/totalLength) * 100;

return Math.round(arrPercent1);
```

The function works fine until I get to ratio 5:3.

The percentages before returning Math.round() is 62.5 are 37.5
which will end up as 63% and 38% which add up to be more than 100%.

How can I get 63 and 37% or 62 and 38% ? thanks

Comment: Be careful, javascript has problems with floating numbers

Comment: In your second line you put var arrLength2 = .length;

Comment: Simple solution is to just take the first rounding and subtract the result from 100 to get the 2nd number. Guaranteed to add up to 100.  `100 - Math.round(arrPercent1)`

Comment: Yay!!! @StevenLambert, Thanks a bunch. ans thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to just take the first rounding and subtract the result from 100 to get the 2nd number. Guaranteed to add up to 100. `100 - Math.round(arrPercent1)`

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round` acts like `Math.ceil` for `x.5` values. You expect it to floor `62.5` and to ceil `37.5`, or the opposite. It's contradictory.

Edit: Steven Lambert should post his solution as an answer and it should be the accepted solution.